# Redirect Network Traffic

Tags: networking, iptables, ufw

I host a Minecraft server at home that I use to play with friends, which they all use to connect to via an OpenVPN server.

The OpenVPN server has the IP (A.A.A.A) and the IP range for the VPN itself is 10.8.1.0/24
The Minecraft server has the VPN IP 10.8.1.2 and is accessible on port 25566

So far; you need to be connected to the VPN to interact with the server, but I want my friends to be able to connect to A.A.A.A:25566 instead.

So far; this is in my UFW and `before.rules`

```
ufw allow proto tcp from any to 159.203.94.186 port 25566
```

`before.rules`

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 159.203.94.186 -p tcp --dport 25566 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.1.2:25566
# setup routing
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.1.2 ! -d 10.8.1.2 -eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

So far, it that the connection goes through but isn't received at 10.8.1.2, or the reply from 10.8.1.2 doesn't come back to A.A.A.A or out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question had an answer:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55791/port-forward-to-vpn-client

This is the final configuration that worked:

```
#/etc/ufw/before.rules
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 159.203.94.186 -p tcp --dport 25566 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.1.2:25566
# setup routing
-A POSTROUTING -d 10.8.1.2 -p tcp --dport 25566 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.1.1
#-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.1.2 ! -d 10.8.1.2 -eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

Comment: Could someone explain how an SNAT works? From what I can tell it changes where it effectively comes from, but where's the return path? How does this deal with multiple clients?